# React-native and Airbnb-maps center layout at bottom

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am currently trying to implement a kind of 'statistics' overlay page.

I have the following code so far:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      ...
    >
    <MapView.Polygon
    ...
    >
    </MapView.Polygon>

      <MapView.Marker coordinate={{latitude: 47.366965, longitude: 8.545102}}>
        <View style={styles.radius}>
          <View style={styles.marker}></View>
        </View>
      </MapView.Marker>

**THIS PART**
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', bottom: 0}}>
      <View style={{width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
      <View style={{width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
      <View style={{width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
    </View>
**THIS PART**

    </MapView>
    <Fab
                    direction="up"
                    containerStyle={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#5067FF' }}
                    position="bottomRight">
    </Fab>
  </View>
```

Now the three containers I get are at the top; how can I focus them to the bottom?

Comment: what about adding `position: 'absolute'` to its style?

Comment: @Cherniv, thanks a lot, I really appreciate your answer! :) the boxes successfully go to the bottom, but the "justifyContent" property is then ignored (all boxed are aligned from left to right without any spacing); any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: try to add `width: '100%'`

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, When I reload the page, sometimes it still appears on the top, and not the bottom.. any idea?

Comment: try to add `width: '100%'; height: '100%'` to your container and map objects styles

Comment: works, thanks a lot!